# Physical reset button on Wi-Fi router case vs. reset settings in web-based router GUI

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, connection, firmware

Can somebody confirm to me whether physical reset button on Wi-Fi router case & reset settings option in web-based management GUI do the same thing? I'm interested in general (for most of devices) and in particular for Asus RT-N66U. 
Basically I have some issues with Wi-Fi connectivity of my devices to router and it has been quite a while since this problem started & it persist through few firmware updates. I'm running latest official firmware for this device, and at some point for some of firmware versions there was a warning that "this version brings loads of new features and reset before applying this required/recommended" - i didn't do it back then. As problems with connectivity became iritating I performed reset through the web GUI - it haven't resolved my issues. So I'm asking about differences between these 2 reset options. I suspect hardware button also will revert roter to initial firmware version and this could be required to resolve my isssues. 
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: With *some* devices, you can use the physical reset button, and some wierd instructions to do a nvram wipe

Comment: Normally the physical reset button will reboot the router without reverting any settings providing you only press it for a short time. Holding the button down typically resets all settings although I'm not sure firmware would normally get reverted too. Best to look for a manual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes both the ways are for the same purpose. Either way will completely reset the router to its factory setting. As for resetting to the initial firmware, you will have to get the firmware files and then flash them to the router yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the master password you must use the physical reset.  Otherwise they are the same.